# Solution of a modified Poisson-Boltzmann equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetism

I'm trying to solve a modified Poisson-Boltzmann equation given by

$\frac{d^{2}\phi(z)}{dz^{2}}=2k_{1}\sinh(\phi(z))-k_{2}$,

where $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are constants, and I'm not sure of how to solve it.

I know that if $k_{2}=0$ then I can multiply both sides by $\frac{d\phi(z)}{dz}$, leading to

$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{d\phi(z)}{dz})^{2}=2k_{1}\sinh(\phi(z))\frac{d\phi(z)}{dz}$,

and integrating once,

$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{d\phi(z)}{dz})^{2}-2k_{1}\cosh(\phi(z))=c$, where $c$ is a constant related to the boundary conditions of the equation.

Then, I define $\psi=\sqrt{4k_{1}\cosh(\phi)+2c}$ and solve $\frac{dz}{d\phi}=\frac{1}{\psi}$.

I know that $\frac{dz}{d\psi}=\frac{dz}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}$, the first term is $1/\psi$ and the other one is $\psi/2k_{1}\sinh(\phi)$, and as $\sinh(\phi)=\sqrt{(\frac{\psi^{2}-2c}{4k_{1}})^{2}-1}$, I get that

$dz=\frac{d\psi}{2k_{1}\sqrt{(\frac{\psi^{2}-2c}{4k_{1}})^{2}-1}}$.

I can probably integrate this, but it looks like it will be nasty.

However, the part that has been bothering me the most is for $k_{2}\neq 0$.

Following the same procedure, once I multiply both sides by $d\phi/dz$ and integrate, I get $k_{2}\phi$.

Then, I define $\psi=\sqrt{4k_{1}\cosh(\phi)+2c+2k_{2}\phi}$ and

$\frac{dz}{d\psi}=\frac{1}{2k_{1}\sinh(\psi)+2k_{2}}$. Now, $\sinh(\phi(z))=\sqrt{(\frac{\psi^{2}-2k_{2}\phi-2c}{4k_{1}})^{2}-1}$ and therefore I get
$\frac{dz}{d\psi}=\frac{1}{2k_{1}\sqrt{(\frac{\psi^{2}-2c-2k_{2}\phi}{4k_{1}})^{2}-1}+2k_{2}}$.

And I'm horribly stuck, as I don't like having $\phi$ down there...
Any suggestions are welcome!!!

Comment: Isn't this better for maths SE?

Answer (score 1):

> I can probably integrate this, but it looks like it will be nasty.

The $k_2=0$ has been discussed in the literature. You do not specify boundary conditions, but the case $\phi(z=0)=\Phi$ and $\phi(z\to\infty)=0$ was famously solved by Gouy in 1910 (SUR LA CONSTITUTION
DE LA CHARGE ÉLECTRIQUE A LA SURFACE D’UN ÉLECTROLYTE, yes, in French) and Chapman in 1913 (A contribution to Electrocapilarity). The same solution in modern notation can be found in Eq. 12 of [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/ijnsns-2013-0039/html) by Chow and coworkers.

Corkill and Rosenhead (1939, [link](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1939.0111)) considered a case wherein $\partial_z \phi(z=L)=0$ for some finite length $L$; this corresponds physically to two like-charged plates separated by a distance $2L$. Their implicit solution can be found in Eq. 3.7 of that paper. Verweij and Overbeek's reproduce these results in chapter IV of their famous 1942 book on colloid stability.

I cannot help you now with the $k_2\neq0$ case, but suggest you to have a look at the above mentioned paper by Chow et al.